# How to find elements in java script using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Handoverscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create New User">
        <form onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="myForm" method="post">
            <label for="Miscellaneous">UserName*:</label>
                <textarea name="textarea" id="Miscellaneous" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" ></textarea>

                <label for="HighPriorityIssues">First Name*:</label>
                <textarea name="textarea" id="HighPriorityIssues" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" ></textarea>
                <label for="CR">Second Name* :</label>
                 <textarea name="textarea" id="CR" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" ></textarea>
                 <label for="Severity">Surname* :</label>
                 <textarea name="textarea" id="Severity" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" ></textarea>
                 <label for="DateOfUpdate">Date of update  :</label>
                 <input type="text" id="datepicker" >
                 <label for="DateOfUpdate">Update By  :</label>
                 <input type="text" id="updateBy" >
                 <label for="DateOfUpdate">Update :</label>
                 <input type="text" id="update" >
                 <label for="DateOfUpdate">Owned By  :</label>
                 <input type="text" id="ownedBy" >

        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
            <h1>User Details:</h1>
            <button id="view">View</button>
            <button id="send">Send</button>
            <button id="create-user">Create</button>
            <button id="download">Download</button>
            <label for="search">Search :</label><input type="text" />

        <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header ">

                     <th><input type="checkbox" onchange = "checkAll(this);" name="chk[]"></th>     
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>First Name/th>
                    <th>Second Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th></th>
                     <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="Check_Click(this);"/> </td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td>Y</td>
                    <td>Z</td>
                    <td>XYZ</td>
                    <td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>

                    </td>
                    <td><span class="delete"><a href="">Delete</a></span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

Java Scrpit File:

```
$(function () {

    var new_dialog = function (type, row) {
        var dlg = $("#dialog-form").clone();
        var miscellaneous = dlg.find(("#Miscellaneous")),
            highPriorityIssues = dlg.find(("#HighPriorityIssues")),
            cr = dlg.find(("#CR")),
            severity = dlg.find(("#Severity"));
        type = type || 'Add ';
        var config = {
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": save_data,
                    "Cancel": function () {
                    dlg.dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                dlg.remove();
            }
        };
        if (type === 'Edit') {
            config.title = "Edit a Handover";
            get_data();
            delete(config.buttons['Create an account']);
            config.buttons['Save'] = function () {
                row.remove();
                save_data();

            };

        }
        dlg.dialog(config);
```

In this scenario when I click on Create button it will opens one dialog box this box code is in java script file 
I want to scrape save and cancel buttons these buttons are in java script file Can any one help me on how to scrape these buttons using Jsoup Below attached image shows description.
![enter image description here][10]

Comment: jsoup can't handle javascript generated content. check selenium webdriver